# 2D list manipulation in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to take a 2D list and add a user given number to the first number of each sublist and make the second number of the sublist the output. Then utilize a separate function to print the entire 2D list. So far this is all I've been able to work out. I can't figure out how to get the indexing to work right with the loops, so I haven't put the display function in yet as I can't get the output right. Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm using Python 3.3

```
ROWS = 5
COLS = 2

def main():

    num1 = int(input('Type a whole number and press ENTER: '))

    values = [[10, 0],
              [13, 0],
              [36, 0],
              [74, 0],
              [22, 0]]

    for r in range(ROWS):
        add = values[0] + num1
        for c in range(COLS):
            c = add

    print(c)
    input('press enter to continue')

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your current loop:

```
for r in range(ROWS): # r is assigned to values 0 to 4 in turn (but never used)
    add = values[0] + num1 # TypeError - can't add integer to (sub-)list
    for c in range(COLS): # c is assigned to values 0 to 1 in turn
        c = add # c is reassigned to add's value
```

This doesn't attempt to update the list, and uses unnecessarily hard-coded values (`ROWS` and `COLS`). The minimal fix is:

```
for r in range(ROWS):
    add = values[r][0] + num1 # note [r]
    for c in range(COLS):
        values[r][c] = add
```

But much neater would be:

```
for row in values:
    add = row[0] + num1
    for index in range(len(row)):
        row[index] = add
```

This will update all values with the first value plus the user's integer. To leave the first integer as it starts, use `range(1, COLS)`/`range(1, len(row))`.